# UITableview in UITableviewcontroller - cellforrowatindexpath not called on reload

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I am stucked in a stupid problem since two days. I have got a `UITableViewController` pushed in `Navigation Controller`. When it loads, since there is no data, so empty table is visible:

[image]

But when I receive data from server, and call `[self.tableView reloadData]`, both `numberOfRowsInSection` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` get invoke except `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and my controller is shown without table:

[image]

I can't really understand that why it is happening. All datasource methods are called except for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Please someone guide me... Thanks..

**ActLogController.h**

```
@interface ActLogController : UITableViewController<ASIHTTPRequestDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property(strong) NSMutableArray *activityKeys;

@end
```

**ActLogController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    activityKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self retrieveActivityLogFromServer];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return activityKeys.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    ActivityLogUnit *act = [activityKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = act.price;

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50.0;
}

-(void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSArray *list = [request.responseString JSONValue];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++) {

        NSArray *singleTrade = [[list objectAtIndex:i] JSONValue];

        ActivityLogUnit *unit = [[ActivityLogUnit alloc] init];

        unit.symbol = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:0];
        unit.type = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:1];
        unit.price = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:2];
        unit.volTraded = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:3];
        unit.remVol = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:4];
        unit.actualVol = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:5];
        unit.recordID = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:6];
        unit.orderNo = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:7];
        unit.time = [singleTrade objectAtIndex:8];

        [activityKeys addObject:unit];

    }

    if(activityKeys.count > 0)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];//it is called and I have got 6 items confirm
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I set some dummy data in my array `activityKeys`, Data is being displayed in table, and `cellforrowatindexpath` **is called successfully**. But as I reload data after sometime, other methods are called except this one and table disappears as shown in 2nd pic. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you connected IBOutlet for tableView ?

Comment: Log activityKeys.count in numberOfRowsInSection to see what it returns.

Comment: @Bhargavi I haven't got xib file for my tableviewcontroller.

Comment: @rdelmar its returning 6. Amazingly `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called 6 times but cellforrow.. zero time.

Comment: Did you set a cell identifier?

Comment: Have you confirmed that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called by logging, or are you assuming that because you see no data.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique yes I have... you can see that from my Q as well.

Comment: @rdelmar I have confirmed by both logging as well as setting breakpoint.

Comment: try adding 
    self.tableView.delegate = self; after the datasource is set

Comment: That's very puzzling -- I can't think of any reason that cellForRowAtIndexPAth wouldn't be called as long as numberOfRowsInSection returns a number greater than 0. Can you post your project somewhere?

Comment: have u added the uitableviewdelegate and uitableviewdatasource in the header file?

Comment: @lakesh, that's irrelevant -- while it's nice to do that since it gives you code completion, it's not necessary.

Comment: Where is your table view coming from? Are you just instantiating a UITableView and getting the default tableView? No xib or storyboard? No custom table view?

Comment: @rdelmar I am just using a default tableview bind up with uitableviewcontroller. There is no storyboard or custom table etc.

Comment: With the default table view, you'll have to register your cell class with the appropriate identifier or else you'll get an error ([self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];). However, I don't think this is your problem, because you would only get that error (which I'm sure you would have mentioned) if cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got it worked. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` was not being called because of a line of code I didn't mention here... which was actually removing some color background layer from view. It was causing reloading issue. After removing it, everything works fine.

Thank you all of you for your cooperation :)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you probably download the data content on a background thread. Since you cannot update the UI on a background you need to call [self.tableView reloadData] on the main thread once the download is finished!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer helped me!  My fix was to use performSelectorOnMainThread to reloadData.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you in secondary thread, do reloadData in main thread by using following code

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]
```

You can always use [NSThread isMainThread] to check whether you are in main thread or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Its not working. Still I get blank white view :(

Comment: As a sanity check, are you sure cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting invoked? breakpoints.. NSLog..

Comment: Yes I have used both and checked that it is not invoked.

Comment: You can replace reloadData call with
    [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5]; //delay to avoid multi-threading issues

Answer (score 4):

you have to write in viewdidload

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

**Edit**

You have no xib then where you are declared/sets your tableview's properties. Like

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 500);
self.tableView.rowHeight = 34.0f;
self.tableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Try with

```
 @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *activityKeys;
```

Comment: I have no xib, but still initially table was shown (1st pic) and also reference is assigned to it. I also tried your answer but it did not help me :(

Comment: when your reload tableview at that time numberOfRowsInSection method called? or not? if called then print it count.

Comment: Yes it gets called. count is 6 after reload.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I strongly believe that the instance name of the tableview should not be similar to the local variable (i.e. tableView in class should not be equal to tableView in delegate and data source methods).

Second in your question posted I could not see the delegate set for the table view.
answer Posted By Samir Rathod should work if you have @property for the table view set in you .h or .m file.

You can also do this if you have a XIB file.
Press ctrl and click + drag the tableview to the files owner and set the delegate and datasource.

Comment: 1st of all, I hadn't got any instance. Secondly, I tried with xib and setting outlet, but still result is same..

Comment: have you logged the counts of the array??? I know you have mentioned it above. but if that is so any count above 0 should call the cellForRowAtIndex. Probably there is a very small step that you must be missing. Try to diagnose your steps again.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was my stubbed-out code returning 0 as the number of sections (so it never asked how many rows were in the section, and never got their data). Just change that to 1 if it's your problem also. Additionally, I was working in Swift, where the issue mentioned by @shahid-rasheed is coded (slightly) differently:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms too. In my case, the first time I loaded the data (from core data) in viewDidLoad, NSSortDescriptor was used to sort the data.

On the click of a button, the core data was fetched again (this time with changes) and tableView data reloaded. It initially gave me a blank table view after the button was clicked because I forgot to sort the data the second time I fetched it.

Learning points: Remember to call all methods which modify the cell (like background color mentioned by iAnum, or NSSortDescriptor in my case) if you have used them in the beginning!